# Why do I need to use self::core::ops?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use `Mul` from `core`.

This is suggested by the compiler and works:

```
extern crate core;

use self::core::ops::Mul;
```

but why doesn't

```
extern crate core;

use core::ops::Mul;
```

work?

I get the error `` error: unresolved import `core::ops::Mul`. Did you mean `self::core::ops`? ``

Comment: Why not `use std::ops::Mul`?

Comment: @mdup because the compiler said `core` and this is a super non-obvious part of Rust :-(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An `extern crate x;` loads `x` into the current namespace. `use` statements are absolute paths unless they start with `self::`, so if you put your `extern crate core;` anywhere but the crate root then you need to specify an absolute path or use `self::`.

```rust
mod foo {
    mod bar {
        extern crate core;
        use foo::bar::core::ops::Mul;
        // or `use self::core::ops::Mul;`
        // or even `use super::bar::core::ops::Mul;` if you’re mad
        // but not `use core::ops::Mul;`.
    }
}
```

… but as a general rule you shouldn’t use `core` directly anyway. All the stable stuff from it is available in `std` which is included automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I am supposed to use `use std::ops::Mul;`.

Comment: Using `libcore` is possible, and is for the situation when you're building without `libstd` at all. Prefer `libstd`, it's what the stable channel of Rust exposes at the moment.